# Restore Windows 8 screenshots default folder

Tags: windows-8, screenshot

I've followed a tutorial to change the default folder for screenshots in Windows 8 (Win + Print Screen).
I chose the desktop folder as default.
Now it's saving all the screenshots there, but I want to change it again to the default location, which is Pictures/Screenshot. How can I do that?

Comment: Please provide us the tutorial you followed.  You would simply follow it again and restore the original value.

Comment: [This one](http://www.howtogeek.com/139350/change-the-location-of-the-default-screenshot-folder-in-windows-8/)

Comment: There is described how restore the original path, as you see in my anwer.

Comment: I followed a tutorial to change the location, now I want to restore it. But I can't do that and I think it's because I put the `desktop` as default folder for screenshots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily restore the default Screenshots folder. To do so, navigate to the custom Screenshots folder to which you changed, right-click in the folder, and select Properties from the popup menu. On the Location tab, click Restore Default. The original default Screenshots folder path is inserted into the edit box. Click OK.

[image]

If you previously moved (not copied) the Screenshots folder, then it doesn’t exist in the original location anymore. Therefore, the Create Folder dialog box displays asking if you want to create the Screenshots folder. Click Yes.

If you have the custom Screenshots folder open in Windows Explorer, you may see an error dialog box, warning you that the selected location is not available (which was the modified one). Click OK.

[Source](http://www.howtogeek.com/139350/change-the-location-of-the-default-screenshot-folder-in-windows-8/)

**EDIT**

If you specify a system folder as a new location, you are not able to revert back to the default state, as a pop up warn you.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried so. I think it's not working because It's the `desktop` folder.

Comment: As a pop up warn you, you can't do that.

Comment: I thought I could change a registry key, or something to change it. If I create another user, do you think it's gonna work?

Comment: Adding a new profile worked for me, that was the solution for now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are like me and have set Desktop folder as your screenshot folder then the accepted answer doesn't work.

You then need to change your screenshot folder using registry as mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/a/1594115/774498)

> In the registry, under the key:
> HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell
> Folders, look for a value named:
> {B7BEDE81-DF94-4682-A7D8-57A52620B86F}

Change that value to point to whatever folder you want to store your screenshots in.

Then restart explorer.exe and it will store screenshots now onwards in the new folder.