# Where is the location of Screenshots folder stored in Windows and how to reset it?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-registry, environment-variables, screenshot

Unfortunately I lost the location of my screenshots folder location.

I frequently change the Screenshots Folder location. I messed up something and now I can't locate the folder. My PC is taking Screenshots normally when I press Win + PrtScr but I can't access my screenshots.

I have tried Windows Search and Recent Files, but nothing works. I can't remember which folder I last assigned to the Screenshots and I have tried all of my usual locations.

How can I get its location? Is it stored in Windows Registry or System Variables?

Or if I can reset the location so that its in the default Pictures folder, it will do the work.

Comment: Go in Explorer to `This PC > Pictures`, right-click `Screenshots`, Properties, and look in the "Location" tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three ways to find it:

1. Click in the Address Bar of Explorer & type: `shell:Screenshots`
2. In the registry, under the key:
   `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`,
   look for a value named:
   `{B7BEDE81-DF94-4682-A7D8-57A52620B86F}`
3. In **PowerShell**

```
(gp 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders').'{B7BEDE81-DF94-4682-A7D8-57A52620B86F}'
```

Comment: **Perfect! Thanks a lot for your help.** This is the most complete SuperUser answer I've ever seen. Kudos to you for your excellent knowledge.

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the location of screenshot is on **This PC**-->**Pictures**-->**Screenshots**

How to modify the save location of screenshots?

Right-click the "*Screenshots*" folder and select the "*Properties*".

In Properties windows, select Location tab and select move button. And then Select a Destination window will open and you can select the location that you want to save these screenshots. And you can also create a new folder, select the corresponding folder as the target, and click the "Save" button. After returning to the "Properties" window, you will find that the "Position" edit box has changed. Just click the "OK" button to save the settings.

And you may try to search "screenshots" folder in File Explorer to see if these screenshots can be found.